Файл package.json в расширении для VS Code автоматически устанавливает текущее расширение как зависимость
Я пытаюсь сделать расширение для VS Code (на JavaScript), которое сжимает код. Оно имеет идентификатор unlinter.
В режиме отладки всё работает, но стоит мне попытаться его экспортировать (vsce package)... В package.json появляется графа зависимостей, которая вызывает ошибку:
 ERROR  Command failed: npm list --production --parseable --depth=99999 --loglevel=error
npm ERR! code ELSPROBLEMS
npm ERR! missing: unlinter@file:, required by unlinter@0.0.1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-11-25T11_22_05_614Z-debug-0.log

Файл package.json:
{
  "name": "unlinter",
  "displayName": "Unlinter",
  "description": "",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "engines": {
    "vscode": "^1.95.0"
  },
  "categories": [
    "Other"
  ],
  "activationEvents": [],
  "main": "./extension.js",
  "contributes": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "command": "unlinter.helloWorld",
        "title": "Hello World"
      }
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "pretest": "npm run lint",
    "test": "vscode-test"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/mocha": "^10.0.6",
    "@types/node": "18.x",
    "@types/vscode": "^1.95.0",
    "@vscode/test-cli": "^0.0.8",
    "@vscode/test-electron": "^2.3.9",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "unlinter": "file:"
  }
}


Что может быть причиной такого поведения?
Как мне экспортировать расширение?
